# How can I show the Facebook authorization screen?

Tags: php, facebook

How can I show the Facebook authorization screen using PHP when the user visits a facebook application?

Comment: Well, I am looking at a code snippet to understand how this can be implemented....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect for an example

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)
Example [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)